# Zoomable AND clickable irregular-shape image map with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I would like to create a zoomable image map containing irregular shapes upon which you can click to go to their link (actually different countries in a simple map of the world).

I have found a few examples of zoomable images using JavaScript and/or jQuery, and a few examples of irregular-shape image maps, but nothing that does both together. I would have thought that this would be popular functionality - surely it has been done a hundred times before? If only I could find where!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://doogalbellend.blogspot.com/2010/03/jquery-zoom-addin-with-image-map.html